# how to make a field read only in php, Zend frame work

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my code for Start date and end date filed, how can I make both the field read only in front end?

```
$('#start_day').datepicker('setDate', '+0');

$('#end_day').datepicker('setDate', '+0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

For Disable

```
$("#start_day, #end_day").prop( "disabled", true );
```